# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl in Weblogic 11g

Tags: java, oracle11g, jaxb, weblogic11g, xerces

I am hitting this error on weblogic 10.3.6. I tried setting the properties

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl

after the above change still no luck, my search for this on weblogic seems is not yielding much information for me to dig further. I understand I am stuck in this Xerces classloader hell.

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I m past this issue now, basically I removed the references to the javax, tattletale tool from Jboss was very helpful to me to understand the class references.